# Show more comments needs to update the LaTeX rendering

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeX formatting in other comments in the same post is lost when the comment list is updated](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/397/tex-formatting-in-other-comments-in-the-same-post-is-lost-when-the-comment-list-i)

Just a javascript call needs added because the LaTeX rending stops when you click show more comments.