# Re-render MathJax in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

A couple of months ago, Kaestur Hakarl wrote a comment in [Feedback on MathJax TeX rendering](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/426/feedback-on-mathjax-tex-rendering/1008#1008) which didn't receive enough attention:

> > ... Is it possible for the re-rendering pass to also cover expanded comments?

Hopefully, we can address that suggestion now.

I know for sure that it is possible to re-render equations in the comment section. A good place to start is [this](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/docs/?typeset.html).

Comment: Thanks for posting this as a question.

Comment: possible duplicate: [TeX formatting in other comments in the same post is lost when the comment list is updated](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/397/tex-formatting-in-other-comments-in-the-same-post-is-lost-when-the-comment-list-i)

Comment: @KennyTM: It's not exactly the same issue, however, it could be solved in the same way. The solution would be to run something like 'MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,comments]' each time a change occurs in the comment section (excluding, of course, the textarea). Actually, you wrote a possible solution, however, it hasn't been implemented since August.

Answer (score 2):

We have wired up MathJax rendering pipeline.